# Wordpress adding a news page with custom template loads wrong template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am building a new website and trying to add a new page for news with a custom template. The only problem is that it does not load the template file I set it to load, instead it loads my homepage template. I figured it had something to do with the [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) but it seems i'm unable to find out or change the fact that it loads a wrong template file.

Things i use atm for news

```
Page:               News

Custom post type:   News

Taxomony tag:       News
```

Perhaps i should change something because they all use the same names.

The URL where I want the custom template to load is
http://www.website.com/news

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I've just noticed that also when I visit any other page that menu button gets highlighted(so you know you are on that page atm.) But when I visit the news page it highlights "Home".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have mentioned, I think you should change the theme file name and check the template settings in Wordpress Backend if you are able to view the template.

For eg

/*
  Template Name: News New
 */

Thanks and Regards
Shiva

Comment: Yes i did this it did change the name in the dropdown box but still it loads my home themplate. Thank you for your time tough.

Comment: Could you check the error log and see if there is any specific file that you are missing .. ?

Comment: Well I have other pages as well for example page Events. with a custom template page-events.php. so basically everything is the same except for "news" turns to "events" and somehow this just works fine. Also checked the logs nothing is off there.

Comment: Does it have any parent category .. the new section .. ? From the looks of it i think its not able to map the theme file. I would suggest to recreate the entire page again from scratch and check if that works.

Comment: Well I did add an related content taxonomy for events and news but that should not be any problem because when i remove the taxonomy and tags its still the same. What I just found out is that when I put the permalink on Default the news page works perfectly fine as it should be. If I change it back to %post-name% then its all screwed again. Also when the setting is enabled for %post-name% and I alter the permalink of the news page to something like http://www.website.com/recent-news instead of just /news it also works just fine.

Comment: Alright, I've found the problem. The problem is with the permalinking and using the same name for post-type and page title. What I believe wordpress did is look for all posts of post-type: "news" and trying to display it on home template. I altered the post-type name to "news-item". Then I altered the permalink to default, save and back on %post-name% and save again. I believe that last part was important. I would like to thank you Shiva for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Create a php file inside your theme folder with the name 'page-news.php'. Copy the same code as your 'page.php' file inside page-news.php. This is the file that will be loaded when you enter http://www.website.be/news. Customize this file as you wish.

Comment: I copied the page.php but somehow it never gets or uses that page. it just goes directly for the home.php themplate. Does it maybe try to load posts or something? Thank you for your time tough.